# Finding total number of combinations in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I have three sorted numbers.I can change only last or ist number to get the number in between the other two.What is the maximum number of changes will i do?

For eg:1,2,5
Ist change will be 2,3,5
Here 1 is changed to the number between 2 and 5
2nd Change will be 3,4,5
So output is 2.
Can anyone tell me better implementation than below?

```
void printCount() {
    int a[] = {0,0,0};
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the input");
    int count1=in.nextInt();
    for (int j=0;j<count1;j++){
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        a[i]=in.nextInt();  
    }
    int count=0;    
    while(true){
        if(a[2]==(a[1]+1) && a[1] ==(a[0]+1)){
            break;
        }
        if((a[1]-a[0]) >a[2]-a[1]){
            a[2]=a[0]+1;
        }
        else{
            a[0]=a[1]+1;
        }
        count++;
        Arrays.sort(a);
    }   
    System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no actual question here. This would be better asked as a code review on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do something like this once you have the array. I might be missing something...

```
int firstDelete = Math.abs(a[2]-a[1])-1;
int thirdDelete = Math.abs(a[0]-a[1])-1;
System.out.println(Math.max(firstDelete, thirdDelete));  //Max count
```